# path('<username>') causing all urls to map to incorrect view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a Django app called `chat` and the root `urls.py` looks like this

```
path('messages/', include('chat.urls')),
```

However the url below, in the chat app `urls.py` is causing problems

```
re_path(r"^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)", login_required(chat_views.ThreadView.as_view()), name='thread'),
```

What is happening is that instead of throwing a 404 does not exist 
error when I go to a made up url such as

```
localhost/messages/blahblah/02
```

It instead throws

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: chat_thread.second_id
```

Because it is assuming `blahblah/02` is a username and is mapping it to  the `ThreadView` which fails to get the `thread` object from 2 users.

So essentially, any other url pattern I try to create in the `chat` app doesn't route properly. (Example I tried creating a `NotificationListView` but couldn't access it due to routing `messages/notifications` to `ThreadView`)

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: This pattern is too general. My suggestion is to prefix it with `user/` or whatever. If you don't want it then make it the very last pattern in urlpatterns list. `fails to get` - actually it looks like it fails to `save` chat_thread.

Comment: Sweet, adding user solved it! If you put it as an answer I'll mark it correct.